Helm installation failed for Overleaf; executing "common.controller.ports" at <.enabled>: can't evaluate field enabled in type interface {}
I'm trying to install Overleaf in my kubernetes cluster using helm, I'm stuck at this error and really don't know how to continue.
error calling include: template: overleaf/charts/common/templates/lib/controller/_ports.tpl:7:11: executing "common.controller.ports" at <.enabled>: can't evaluate field enabled in type interface {}  

I've used helm to download the helm chart and the file _ports.tpl
1.  {{/*
2.   Ports included by the controller.
3.   */}}
4.   {{- define "common.controller.ports" -}}
5.     {{- $ports := list -}}
6.     {{- range .Values.service -}}
7.       {{- if .enabled -}}
8.         {{- range $name, $port := .ports -}}
9.           {{- $_ := set $port "name" $name -}}
10.          {{- $ports = mustAppend $ports $port -}}
11.        {{- end }}
12.      {{- end }}
13.    {{- end }}

I've followed what was provided in their values.yaml file
    service:
      # -- Enable a service for the code-server add-on.
      enabled: true
      type: ClusterIP
      # Specify the default port information
      ports:
        codeserver:
          port: 12321
          enabled: true
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: codeserver
          ## Specify the nodePort value for the LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.
          ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport
          ##
          # nodePort:
      annotations: {}
      labels: {}

and have included the following in my yaml file
  values:
    service:
      enabled: true
      type: ClusterIP

I can't figure out why it is still saying that it can't find a value for enabled in .Values.service .

In your Helm code, you have a range loop over .Values.service
{{- range .Values.service -}}
  {{- if .enabled -}}
    ...
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}

That most likely implies that service is intended to be a list, not a single item
# at the top level of values.yaml
service:
  - enabled: true
    ports: [...]
  - enabled: false
    ports: [...]

With the structure of values file you've shown, service: itself isn't a list, and you don't need this range loop.  You could change it to a with statement to rebind the . special variable, and not change code
{{- with .Values.service -}}{{/* only change the first word of this line */}}
  {{- if .enabled -}}
    ...

or spell out the references to the specific values.
{{- if .Values.service.enabled -}}
  {{- range $name, $port := .Values.service.ports -}}
    ...

(I feel like I see the second form in many real-world charts, repeating .Values.container, but myself I'd write the first.)
